# Get Exif info from photo

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stream, photo, exif

I want to read exif info from Photo using ExifLib, first way is finished because I used `PhotoChooserTask` and `photoChooserTask.Completed += (s, e) => {PhotoConverter.GetMetaData(e);}`
and method for get exif info

```
public static void GetMetaDate(PhotoResult e)
{     
    ExifLib.JpegInfo info = ExifLib.ExifReader.ReadJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    App.MainViewModel.MetaDate = ReadExif(info);
}

private static string ReadExif(JpegInfo info)
{
    JsonObject metaDate = new JsonObject();
    metaDate.Add("FNumber", info.FNumber);
    return metaDate.ToString();
}
```

and it is work great, but the problem is when I want to share picture from phone's gallery. My way to get picture looks like this

```
if (queryStrings.ContainsKey("FileId"))
{
     MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
     Picture photoFromLibrary = library.GetPictureFromToken(queryStrings["FileId"]);
     BitmapImage bitmapFromPhoto = new BitmapImage();
     bitmapFromPhoto.SetSource(photoFromLibrary.GetImage());
}
```

So, how I should change my GetMetaDate to read `photoFromLibrary.GetImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find easy way

```
public static void GetMetaData(Stream photo)//change to stream
{
    ExifLib.JpegInfo info = ExifLib.ExifReader.ReadJpeg(photo);
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(photo);
    App.MainViewModel.MetaDate = ReadExif(info);
}
```

and in place with MediaLiblary add stream

```
if (queryStrings.ContainsKey("FileId"))
{
     // Retrieve the photo from the media library using the FileID passed to the app.
     MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
     Picture photoFromLibrary = library.GetPictureFromToken(queryStrings["FileId"]);

     //Get metadate
     Stream stream = photoFromLibrary.GetImage();
     PhotoConverter.GetMetaData(stream);
}
```